# Not able to find out the correct general solution.

Tags: complex-numbers

I just want to know what mistake am I doing in this question

> Show that the roots of the equation $(1+x)^{2n}+(1-x)^{2n}=0$ are given by $x=\pm i tan\frac{(2k+1)\pi}{4n}$ where $k=0,1,2,3,...,n-1$

So I did the following steps:$$ (1+x)=[(-1)^{\frac{1}{2}}]^{\frac{1}{n}}(1-x) $$
$$(1+x)=(i)^{\frac{1}{n}}(1-x)$$
wrting $i=e^{(2k\pi+\frac{\pi}{2})}$ gives x as 
$$ x=\frac{e^{i (\frac{(4k+1)\pi}{2n})}-1}{e^{i (\frac{(4k+1)\pi}{2n})}+1} = i tan\frac{(4k+1)\pi}{4n}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Writing as an answer to your question in comment . Complex numbers dont act like real numbers so every time it isnt that $(a^b)^c=a^{b.c}$ where $a$ is a complex number of form $x+iy$

Answer (score 1):

We have $$\left(\dfrac{1+x}{1-x}\right)^{2n}=-1=e^{(2m+1)\pi i}$$

$$\implies\dfrac{1+x}{1-x}=e^{(2m+1)\pi i/2n}$$ where $0\le m<2n$

Apply componendo & Dividendo

$$x=\dfrac{e^{(2m+1)\pi i/2n}-1}{e^{(2m+1)\pi i/2n}+1}$$

Divide the numerator & the denominator by $e^{(2m+1)\pi i/4n}$

$$x=\dfrac{e^{(2m+1)\pi i/4n}-e^{-(2m+1)\pi i/4n}}{e^{(2m+1)\pi i/4n}+e^{-(2m+1)\pi i/4n}}$$

Now use Euler formula $e^{ix}=\cos x+i\sin x$

Comment: yes this is the answer. But I want to know whether there is any problem in writing $(-1)^{\frac{1}{2n}}=(i)^{\frac{1}{n}}$

Comment: @anubhav, Why not $$(-i)^{1/n}$$ and $$i^{1/n}$$

Comment: But $\sqrt{-1}=i$ and I am saying that
$$ (-1)^{\frac{1}{2n}}=[(-1)^{\frac{1}{2}}]^{\frac{1}{n}}=[\sqrt{-1}]^{\frac{1}{n}}=i^{\frac{1}{n}} $$
I am sorry if its too obvious but I am still not able to understand my mistake.

Comment: @anubhav, See http://www.sosmath.com/CBB/viewtopic.php?t=35134